# What is the `helper.js` file in Angular / Webpack projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, webpack

I'm trying to understand what is the role [**(*from docs*) of the `helper.js` file**](https://angular.io/guide/webpack#mat-tab-label-0-4) when used with Angular/webpack.

I assume it has to do something with relative dir location. But I don't understand what is the problem at first place which it solves.

Actually this is the file :

```
var path = require('path');
var _root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');

function root(args) {
  args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
  return path.join.apply(path, [_root].concat(args));
}

exports.root = root;
```

**Question:**

What problem does this file solve ?

<sub>An example of a situation *without using this file* vs *using this file* will be much appreciated.</sub>

Comment: It helps us to solve problem with paths on different platform and keep DRY  principle

Comment: https://webpack.github.io/docs/troubleshooting.html#windows-paths

Comment: With this helper we can also declare webpack config wherever we want, it will keep the right path relatively to root dir

Comment: @yurzui Thank you. But  what do you mean by "_wherever we want_" ?  the json is in the root where `package.json` is. no ?  and how does `exports.root` is used by webpack ?

Comment: Usually we keep webpack.config.json in root folder. But sometimes it is handy to move it to dedicated folder like `/config/webpack/webpack.config.json`

Comment: Thank you @yurzui _like always_. so in you last comment (where it has 2 depth) - how would the file will look like ? `path.resolve(__dirname, '../../');` ?

Comment: Look at this config https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/tree/master/config. The have different webpack configs for dev, prod and test. And also common config. And all these configs supply `helpers` module

Comment: `how would the file will look like ?` It might be like `helpers.root('desiredFolder', 'desiredFile')`

Comment: So if we want to refer to tsconfig.json that is inside root dir we just write `helpers.root('tsconfig.json`)` We don't worry about `.../../` We always start from root. Helpers calculate it for us. We only should care about its code.(`var _root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');`) The preceding code is supposed that helpers resides in some folder that is direct child to the root. (That's because `helpers.js` resides in `config/helpers.js` in angular tutorial)

Comment: @yurzui But looking at this line in my code : _`var _root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');`_ - it takes a dirname and go one level up. so what does it means - going level up the root ? there isn't such

Comment: `__dirname` is the directory name of the current module.

Comment: `_root`  variable is calculated once and then is used to construct other paths

Comment: But looking only at `var _root = path.resolve(__dirname, '..');` - there is only 2 dots. Which means -  exactly one level up. So this specific file is regarding a project that the configs are under one level. And if there were `root/sub/config` - so the file would have looked like :  `var _root = path.resolve(__dirname, '../..');`. Right ?

Comment: Yes, you can test it yourself indeed)

Answer (score 0):

`Helper.js` is used to provide the application with custom path as root.

`Export.root = root` accepts the absolute path and set the path as root for particular operation. See the example below:

```
output: {
    **path: helpers.root('dist'),**
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js'
  },
```